# Who is calling paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing

For some reason, my paintComponent(Graphics g) method is being called infinitely. I can't seem to tell who is calling it, even if I dump a StackTrace in the call (it's an event that's dispatched and handled).

Are there any easy ways to find out who's triggering the event?

***Update:*** I've found the cause and I now understand the reason. Whoever answers it correctly will get the answer to the question.

Here is the code that's causing the issue:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    myJButton.setIcon(ResourceLoader.getImageIconWithLocale(MY_BUTTON_IMAGE));
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

***FYI:*** It's a really tricky one!! It's not obvious by looking at the code. I made an assumption that was wrong.

Comment: Do you have a sample code to share?

Comment: If it is being called "infinitely" then you have a loop somewhere in your code that is causing the problem. Swing will only repaint components as required. If you need more help post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr: I've just added some source code as I've discovered the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The setIcon(ImageIcon) will revalidate and repaint itself *ONLY* if the ImageIcon is another instance.**

When working with Locales, most people are use to the ResourceBundle, which returns Strings, which in turn are immutable. Therefore setting the text over and over doesn't matter.

However, in this case, the ResourceLoader (custom class) returned a new instance of an ImageIcon. Sure it was the same Image, but it was another instance. And if you decompile the code, you'll see that setIcon (at least for JButtons), it will repaint and revalidate if newIcon != oldIcon.

The solution was to use a HashMap in the ResourceLoader, this way it saves from loading the images more than once since most of the images are used very frequently (might as well reuse the instances if you can). Turns out that overall this quick adjustment also saved a decent amount of overall memory consumption as an added bonus.

Comment: It is still not a good idea to change a property in the paintComponent() method. You can't control, when or how often the method is invoked by the RepaintManager. If you have functionality the allows the user to change locales dynamically, then you should also have a routine that loops through all components that are affected and have them update themselves rather than customizing the paintComponent() method of every component.

Comment: I thought about that, but this can get really insanely complex very quickly. Imagine trying to keep track of every component in Microsoft Outlook. By going this route, I can force a repaint on the main JFrame/JWindow which can then force a repaint on all sub-components. And as an added bonus, there's very little code, and most importantly no code sprinkled everywhere to help the Locale Manager keep track of all the components, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which component this is, but setting an icon on a button from within a paint routine is a bad idea. It will definitely cause the button to be repainted. If the button is a child of your component then setting the button invalidate the component too causing an infinite loop.

Set the icon somewhere else such as where the dialog / window is set up initially.

Comment: Close!! You're very close. It won't definitely cause it to be repainted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `repaint()` anywhere? Also, when a window becomes visible (uncovered or deminimized) or is resized, the "system" automatically calls the `paintComponent()` method for all areas of the screen that have to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the icon in the paintComponent() method. You should never set a property in this method.

Swing components are smart enough to repaint themselves whenever a property changes. In this case you have the problem of the component repainting itself because the Icon changes, but you are also rereading the Icon every time the component repaints itself which is also not very efficient.

Comment: The reason to set it here is so that if I change the Locale, all I need to do is fire an event on the parent component and all children component will be repainted with the new text.